# Configure Ingress-Nginix in Cluster Kubernetes in 2 Namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Good afternoon

I am working with ingress-nginx for service exposure in an on-premise kubernetes cluster. In this cluster we manage 2 Environment: Development (DEV) and Quality (QA).

What we want is to somehow have 1 ingress-nginx for each environment (DEV and QA), but so far I have not been able to configure it, I am applying the following configuration but I cannot do that for the IP indicated in the controller between the requests according to the environment, example:

DEV environment

**controller-deployment-dev.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.15
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.1.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-dev
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-dev
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-dev
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-dev
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-dev
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-dev
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-dev
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: 10.164.7.203:37003/tmve/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            - --default-ssl-certificate=develop/srvdevma1-ssl
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 512Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: tcold016 
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

**controller-svc-dev.yaml**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.1.1
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      name: ingress-nginx-controller-dev
      annotations:
        metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: shared-ip
      namespace: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
      loadBalancerIP: 10.161.169.12
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        - name: http
          port: 80
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: http
          appProtocol: http
        - name: https
          port: 30000
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: https
          appProtocol: https
      selector:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-dev
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-dev
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-dev
```

**rules ingress dev**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-develop
  namespace: develop
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: srvdevma1-ssl
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/FindComplementaryAccountInfo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: find-complementary-account-info
            port:
              number: 8083
      - path: /api/FindLimitedPackageBS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: find-limited-package
            port:
              number: 8082             
      - path: /api/SendSMSBS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: send-sms
            port: 
              number: 8084              
      - path: /api/SubscribeLimitedPackageCS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: subscribe-limited-package
            port: 
              number: 8085
```

To consume services in the development environment we use the ip indicated in the controller-deployment-dev and port 30000

**https://10.161.169.12:30000/api/FindLimitedPackageBS**
**https://10.161.169.12:30000/api/FindComplementaryAccountInfo**

**QA environment**

For the quality environment I have the following configuration, very similar to that of develop, only with a different IP:

**controller-deployment-qa.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.15
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.1.1
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-tcold
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-qa
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-qa
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-qa
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-qa
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-qa
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-qa
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: 10.164.7.203:37003/tmve/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            - --default-ssl-certificate=develop/srvdevma1-ssl
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 512Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: tcolt022
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

**controller-svc-qa.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.1.1
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-qa
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: shared-ip
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  loadBalancerIP: 10.161.173.45
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      appProtocol: http
    - name: https
      port: 30000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
      appProtocol: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-qa
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-qa
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-qa
```

**rules ingress qa**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-calidad
  namespace: calidad
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: srvdevma1-ssl
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/FindComplementaryAccountInfo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: find-complementary-account-info
            port:
              number: 8083
      - path: /api/FindLimitedPackageBS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: find-limited-package
            port:
              number: 8082             
      - path: /api/SendSMSBS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: send-sms
            port: 
              number: 8084              
      - path: /api/SubscribeLimitedPackageCS
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: subscribe-limited-package
            port: 
              number: 8085
```

And so you should be able to consult the services in this environment, with respect to development you should only change the IP:

**https://10.161.173.45:30000/api/FindLimitedPackageBS**
**https://10.161.173.45:30000/api/FindComplementaryAccountInfo**

Is there any way to do what I indicate through ingress-nginx, with the condition that it is required to maintain the same rules for the services but in different namespaces

**Update**

I managed to find a solution through the following very good documentation:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this use case by using Ingress Classes. Ingresses can be implemented by different controllers, often with different configurations. Each Ingress should specify a class, a reference to an IngressClass resource that contains additional configuration including the name of the controller that should implement the class.

You can deploy two Ingress controllers by granting them control over two different IngressClasses, then selecting one of the two IngressClasses with ingressClassName. Ensure the `--controller-class=` and `--ingress-class` are set to something different on each ingress controller.

Firstly, specify **`'--controller-class=k8s.io/internal-ingress-nginx'`** and **`'--ingress-class=k8s.io/internal-nginx'`** in the ingress-nginx deployment. Then use the same value of controller-class in the IngressClass. And refer to that IngressClass in your Ingress using `ingressClassName`. Refer [Multiple Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/) for more information on how to set Ingress class.

**Note:** If `--controller-class` is set to the default value of `k8s.io/ingress-nginx`, the controller will monitor Ingresses with no class annotation and Ingresses with annotation class set to nginx. Use a non-default value for `--controller-class`, to ensure that the controller only satisfied the specific class of Ingresses.

You can configure the Ingress Controller to handle configuration resources only from a particular namespace, which is controlled through the **`-watch-namespace`** command-line argument. This can be useful if you want to use different NGINX Ingress Controllers for different applications, both in terms of isolation and/or operation.

**`-watch-namespace`** is used to watch Namespace for Ingress resources. By default the Ingress Controller watches all namespaces.

Refer [Running Multiple Ingress Controllers](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/) for more information.